# Adaptive width layout just with css3?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having a lot of trouble figuring this one out, essentially I have 3 columns: navbar (dark gray), main content (dark red) and sidebar (dark green) where navbar can be expanded and shrinked and sidebar can slide out and slide in (so change width from 0 to something and back to 0). And I want to keep all of this responsive. Idea is to shrink main content accordingly when some or both navbar and sidebar are expanded. unfortunately only way I can think to do this is to change width of main content to something like `width: calc(100% - navbar width - sidebar width)` but this is really verbose when I need to check if sidbar is expanded or navbar, or both are not expanded etc...

Here is an image illustrating how main content shrinks:

[image]

I assume flexbox could be used here somehow, but was not able to figure it out.

let example marku be

```
<nav> </nav>
<main> </main>
<aside> </aside>
```

**note:** nav and aside need to be 100% height of the page and are fixed in place.

Comment: I think best option here is to make `nav` and `aside` fixed and when you open them, they go over your content, or other option is, if nav is opened and you click on aside you close `nav` and other way around and content is pushed to side.

Comment: @NenadVracar I was thinking about it, I wouldn't want them to go over, but I will definitely close one if other is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-box` for this. A simple approach would be as follows: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgVVJb

You can change the classes to see how it changes the layout. NOTE: I am using classes to change the width of the columns but you could use JavaScript or static CSS similarly.

Code dump:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="small">Nav</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div class="medium">Sidebar</div>
</div>

html, body, div {
  height: 100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: gray;
}

.small {
  max-width: 50px;
}

.medium {
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

One popular solution to this is putting all of these elements in a wrapper with position: relative or even putting setting body's to position: relative, and all the elements inside with position: absolute. Then you can set each element as follows:

```
.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50px;
}

.main-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 150px;

 }

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 150px;
 }
```

Of course the container element need to have some height for this to work.

Comment: This approach is something similar to what I had, as my sidebars and navs will be expanding with transition etc.. this approach becomes very verbose when adjusting positions like right 150px etc..